# Why am I getting only 50 Mbps on my secondary router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet, internet-connection

I got a 100 Mbps Airtel fiber connection installed yesterday. I was getting a constant speed of 120 Mbps but as I was not getting range on the ground floor, I connected my 5 GHz primary router to 2.4 GHz router through a Cat 5e Ethernet cable (LAN to LAN), but still I am getting only 40 Mbps. What should I do to increase my internet speed?

Comment: You are aware that 2.4 GHz is significantly slower than 5.0 GHz right?  I assume we are talking about WiFi 5 not WiFi 6.  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting commentary

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - Based on the author's statement they have two routers.  I would rather have the author [edit] their question instead of us assuming we know what they meant.  However, based on what the author said, 2.4 GHz clients should see significantly lower speeds than 5.0 GHz clients.  5.0 GHz is faster but has a disadvantage of smaller ranges.

Comment: What model router(s). It may be your router simply can't handle the required packets per second.

Comment: @Ramhound I have two routers both are single band routers which are connected through ethernet to my primary router, but the problem is Dlink is giving me 94 Mbps speed whereas mercusys is giving me only 46mbps speed. why mercusys is giving me only 46mpbs speed .

Comment: You still need to [edit] your question.  I am not hearing anything unusual